# su <user> -c "sudo -l > some_file adding line breaks

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel, ksh

Getting a really strange problem that I cant really get my head around at all. I am running a script as root to check a number of sudo rules are present as user X. When I run:

```
su $USER -c "sudo -l > $USER_sudo_rules.lst"
```

Its wrapping a couple of lines. Lines should appear as:

```
(oracle) NOPASSWD: /opt/oracle/oracle_base/product/*/OPatch/opatch lsinventory
(oracle) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cat /opt/oracle/*/diag/tnslsnr/*/listener_*/trace/*
```

but instead seem to be outputting as:

```
(oracle) NOPASSWD: /opt/oracle/oracle_base/product/*/OPatch/opatch
lsinventory
(oracle) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cat
/opt/oracle/*/diag/tnslsnr/*/listener_*/trace/*
```

I have no idea why. I have tried all sorts piping `sudo -l` into various other tools such as cat, less, fold to try and manipulate the output but nothing at all seems to have an impact. Maybe I can do some post processing to join them back up but was hoping for something cleaner. SHELL is ksh on Redhat. This "$USER_sudo_rules.lst" file will be compared against a pre-defined "sudo rules list" to ensure the correct rules are present on a host.

Comment: Did you check if this is one line or are two lines?

Comment: definitely just one line

Comment: I mean in output file. Open it in editor and check